# Calculate the Gaussian filter's sigma using the kernel's size

Tags: opencv, filtering, gaussian

I find on the [OpenCV documentation for cvSmooth](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaussiankernel) that sigma can be calculated from the kernel size as follows:
sigma = 0.3(n/2 - 1) + 0.8

I would like to know the theoretical background of this equation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Using such a value for sigma, the ratio between the value at the centre of the kernel and on the edge of the kernel, found for `y=0` and `x=n/2-1`, is:

```
g_edge / g_center = exp(-(x²+y²)/(2σ²))
                  = exp(-(n/2-1)²/(2*(0.3(n/2-1)+0.8)²))
```

The limit of this value as `n` increases is:

```
exp(-1/(2*0.3²)) = 0.00386592
```

Note that `1/256` is `0.00390625`. Images are often encoded in 256-value ranges. The choice of `0.3` ensures that the kernel considers all pixels that may significantly influence the resulting value.

I am afraid I do not have an explanation for the `0.8` part, but I imagine it is here to ensure reasonable values when `n` is small.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please forgive my ignorance, I cannot see the effect of having exp(-1/(2*0.3²)) = 0.00386592, which corresponds to 1/256. I would be very grateful if you could give an easier explanation.

Besides, shouldn't we take the farthest pixel at (x=n/2-1, y=n/2-1) instead of (x=n/2-1, y=0)?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you dropping the first part of the gaussian bell equation? 1/(2pi sigma^2)

Comment: @filip because it gets cancelled in `g_edge / g_center`, as it appears on both sides of the division.

Comment: Also, could you maybe explain @AimingHigh 's comment too? :)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Multiply or divide by 6 depending on which of the two you want to generate. Works well with 8bit precision kernels.

Comment: I don't thinks this make sense at all. First the n usually quite small, 2 to 9. if you mean n = ksize -1 ; 2nd, the g_edge/g_center is actually quite big when n = 2, this means sigma = 0.8; which is way to large

Answer (score 0):

We can see if the radius is big enough, it is actually 0.3r, match the sigma assumption: we need the filter radius to be 3sigma

the radius is (ksize-1)/2, thus in another words we need sigma = (ksize-1)/6.
which is roughly 0.15*(ksize-1).

However, why we need the `+0.5` ?

It is very simple. If we make the edge to be 0 for the small kernels,
then only the centre has relatively big value.
It becomes a per pixel scaling instead of filtering.
For radius of 2, It looks like a triangle filter instead of gaussian

Thus we need an offset to make sure the small filter do have low pass effect.

[image]

```
size=3                 : tensor([0.0109, 0.9783, 0.0109])
size=3 with +0.5 offset: tensor([0.2466, 0.5067, 0.2466])
size=5                 : tensor([0.0066, 0.1942, 0.5983, 0.1942, 0.0066])
size=5 with +0.5 offset: tensor([0.0809, 0.2434, 0.3515, 0.2434, 0.0809])
size=7                 : tensor([0.0044, 0.0540, 0.2420, 0.3991, 0.2420, 0.0540, 0.0044])
size=7 with +0.5 offset: tensor([0.0366, 0.1113, 0.2167, 0.2707, 0.2167, 0.1113, 0.0366])
size=9                 : tensor([0.0033, 0.0238, 0.0972, 0.2260, 0.2994, 0.2260, 0.0972, 0.0238, 0.0033])
size=9 with +0.5 offset: tensor([0.0204, 0.0578, 0.1216, 0.1900, 0.2205, 0.1900, 0.1216, 0.0578, 0.0204])
```